'Imperfect' squarings of a square
Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square
This is a planar version of the question at Cubing the cube - as 'perfectly' as possible.
Question: How does one cut a square into the least number of squares that are all mutually non-congruent - except that 2 of the smaller squares are allowed to be congruent? One would hope that the number of square pieces would less than 21 when a pair of duplicates are allowed (21 being the least number of squares in a perfect squaring of the square, as discovered by Duijvestijn).
Note: It seems one can replace "2" above with "3" or "2 pairs" to generate other questions (but not "4" because that will trivialize the problem).
A possibly related question: Which is the rectangle that can be perfectly squared (cut into mutually non-congruent squares) with the least number of square pieces? This must be known stuff; am not able to locate a reference.

The fewest pieces in a squared rectangle is nine. It's given at http://www.squaring.net/sq/sr/spsr/o9/order9_spsr.html and much info can be found at other parts of the site http://www.squaring.net/sq/tws.html

Thanks very much! that settles the 'auxiliary question'. The idea was if a perfectly squared rectangle of dimensions in ratio 2:1 ( 3:2) could be found, one could attach 2 (3) squares both (all) of same size to it to form a perfectly squared square with 2 (3) squares identical. looking through that very long list, i haven't been able to find any such rectangle yet. But then, this need not be the only way to attack the main question!

Here's a squared 2:1 rectangle; http://www.squaring.net/history_theory/gfx/o22-2x1-136-272.png

Thank you. but this will give us an imperfectly squared square with 23 smaller squares which needs more squares than Duijvestijn's best perfect squaring that needs only 21 squares. ideally, by allowing a pair of duplicates, one would hope to reduce the number of squares needed! or is it that by allowing that kind of imperfection, one won't gain anything? more likely, this way of imperfect squaring via first perfect squaring a rectangle is not a very good approach!

I don't understand. You wanted a perfectly squared $2:1$ rectangle. Isn't that what's in the link in my comment? Doesn't it give you a squared square with two squares identical, by the construction you describe in your comment?

Yes. the rectangle was indeed 2:1 and perfectly squared. It does lead to a 'squaring of the square with one pair of duplicates' with 23 smaller squares. My difficulty was that this layout needs more squares than the optimal perfect (without duplicates) squaring of the square - the hope was that allowing a pair of duplicates would lead to a squaring of the square with less than 21 squares. Thanks.

It looks like the proprietor of the website is Stuart Anderson; stuart.errol.anderson AT gmail.com – maybe it's worth contacting him with your questions?

Did you try to contact Anderson?

Yes I did. No word from there
